# how can I build the RTL8192SE driver?

Tags: drivers, compiling, kali-linux, realtek

while trying to build it (executing install.sh), manny, many compiler warnings/errors appear:

```
error: implicit declaration of function 'daemonize' [-Werror=implicit-function-declaration]
warning: cast from pointer to integer of different size [-Wpointer-to-int-cast]
etc...
etc...
```

I know the same problem has been fixed/worked around with other drivers, for instance [here](http://ubuntuforums.org/showthread.php?t=2092934&p=12620866#post12620866) for rtl8188CU driver.

**Is there any fix/workaround which can make the complilation work for the RTL8192SE?**

Thanks.

(I don't want the pre-installed driver because it does not allow me to get in monitor mode)

EDIT: You can download the drivers ISO [here](https://ftp.csl-computer.com/pub/drivers/network/22844-CSL_USB_WLAN_Adapter_300_MB_ext_Antenne/22844-CSL_USB_WLAN_Adapter_300M_ext_Antenne.iso) (containing windows, OSX and Linux versions). I use kali-linux Sana (2.0), with kernel 4.0.0-kali1-amd64. gcc version is 4.9.2.

Comment: You might get a better response if you included a link to the driver source code that you are trying to build, and details of your OS and kernel version

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Often the driver code for Linux you find at random sites (i.e., not in the vanilla kernel code, or some dedicated repo with kernel sources for a family of related devices) is way, way out of date with respect to the kernel sources you are trying to build against. Linux development moves ahead at breakneck speed, 24/7. No wonder the build fails.

Look for people working on this device (perhaps start with the names cited in the vanilla driver or perhaps its in-kernel documentation). There might be something in staging.

Comment: Well, the driver i downloaded from the official repository works as a charm but refuses to go in monitor mode, so i thought this would be the way to go...?

Comment: By the way, this is not a "random site", this is the wlan interface manufacturer's one :(

Comment: @MagixKiller, *what* official repository? For your distribution? Note that fooling around building your own drivers is *not* for the faint of heart/newbies...

Comment: Well, Kali repository I guess. It worked plug&play, so the driver has been download from somewhere hasn't it?

Comment: @MagixKiller, that is exactly the kind of sites to be avoided like the plague. Either the manufacturer has half a clue, and has engineers working (semi)officially with the upstream kernel folks, or they slap together some random source that *somewhat* works with *one* kernel version (often a heavily patched one for some particular distribution), post it at their site and leave it to go moldy.

Comment: Okay I get it... So apart from compiling the driver is there any way i can put this wlan interface in monitor mode?

Comment: @MagixKiller, the driver provided by your distribution is probably from the official kernel sources.

Comment: @MagixKiller, perhaps you should ask a question specifically about how to get that card on your distribution to do what your want. Look for [XY question](http://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/66377/what-is-the-xy-problem)...

Comment: Wow. This question is clearly an XY question then... I apologise :( and will ask another on how I do the thing I want. Thank you